# How to allow only even numbers in EditText in TextWatcher?

Tags: android, textwatcher

I need to enter only even numbers ranging from 0 to 20 in an `EditText`. However when I am pressing keys '1' and '2' to give 12, it is giving me a `Toast` that my input is invalid before I get to press key '2'.

**Textwatcher**:

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
  try {
    int val = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    if (val > 20) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "20", 0, 2);
    } else if (val < 0) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "0", 0, 1);
    } else if (val == 1) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "1", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 3) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "3", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 5) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "5", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 7) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "7", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 9) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "9", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 11) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "11", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 13) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "13", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 15) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "15", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 17) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "17", 0, 2);
    } else if (val == 19) {
      s.replace(0, s.length(), "19", 0, 2);
    }
  } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"invalid!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Instead of testing the input on every single character the user enters, it would be simpler to just have them type in the number, then hit a submit button to send the entire value to your odd/even test. Then you could just do a `if(val % 2 == 0) //the val is even;`

Comment: Where should i add your code because when i added it remained the same.

Answer (score 1):

You will get a `afterTextChanged` call for pretty much every number press so currently you would never be able to write 12.

The best way would be to validate it after the user moves on (loses focus, another item pressed) and alert them if it is't correctly formatted.

Alternatively you could kick off a `runnable` to check it after a few seconds have passed.

As for changing it, would be easier to do

```
public void postUpdateValidate(int val){
    if(val % 2 == 1){ //Checks to see if the remainder is 1 after dividing by 2
      val++;
    }
    if(val > 20){
      val = 20;
    }
    if(val % 0){
      val = 0;
    }
    edittext.setText("" + val);
}
```